# PHP array reference issue with ?? operator

Tags: php

```
<?php
$all_stock_data = [
    "kit_38320" => [
        "law" => [
            1724 => [
                'id' => 320044,
                'reserved' => 4
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

foreach($all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] ?? [] as &$section_stock){
    $section_stock['reserved'] += 1;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($all_stock_data);
```

if a use "?? []" in foreach reserved count is not increase.
who can explain this?

```
if(empty($all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"])){
    $all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] = [];
}
foreach($all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] as &$section_stock){
    $section_stock['reserved'] += 1;
}
```

Thank u for answers. I think its better way

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I’d ditch the reference, and just go with `foreach( $all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] ?? [] as $idx => $section_stock) { $all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"][$idx]['reserved'] += 1; }` here. Accessing `$all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"]` inside the loop is uncritical, because if that wasn’t set, the loop doesn’t iterate a single time in the first place.

Comment: This solves my problem, but I wanted to use the short variable for both ram usage and clean code.

Answer (score 1):

(not sure of the terminology but) It is effectively creating a copy of the value as

```
$all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] ?? []
```

is an expression, so the `foreach` is operating over the result of the expression and not the `$all_stock_data` array.

If you add some extra displays to show the values...

```
foreach($all_stock_data["kit_38320"]["law"] ??[] as &$section_stock){
    print_r($section_stock);
    $section_stock['reserved'] += 1;
    print_r($section_stock);
}
```

you get the value is being updated

```
Array
(
    [id] => 320044
    [reserved] => 4
)
Array
(
    [id] => 320044
    [reserved] => 5
)
```

but this isn't in the `$all_stock_data` array.